# where is the Oracle Event Log located?

Tags: linux, oracle, logging

Where is the location of my oracle event log (on a default Linux installation)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
select value from v$parameter where name = 'background_dump_dest'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using @[cagcowboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197033/where-is-the-oracle-event-log-located#197108), a default [Oracle XE](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html) installation on Linux writes out to:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/admin/XE/bdump
```