# cannot connect to Oracle Database 11g Express Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I am trying to locally connect to Oracle Database 11g Express Edition
Previously when I used to go to Programs > Oracle Database 11g Express Edition > Getting started
it used to show me the page to login in the browser and I could login and view everything.

But now, as soon as I click on Getting started, it goes to the URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950
```

but says "...could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8080"

Please help me. I have no idea where to get started. How do I troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: This is more something for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: That's not really the database, that's the administration console. Is the `OracleDBConsoleorcl` service up and running?

Comment: In depends on your OS. On Windows 7, you click on the "Start" button and type "services.msc" (or you type "Services" in your language until the service manager shows up).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the service of oracle-xe is running if you are using winOS,
and you could "ps -ef" if you are using linuxOS. If the service and daemon
is up and running then paste the log of your bdump.

[where is the Oracle Event Log located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197033/where-is-the-oracle-event-log-located)

Shows you the how to.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is with the windows authentication mode.

What you can try is editing sqlnet.ora file.

Original - SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

Change to- SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (**NONE**)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on windows10- could not use the 'Get Started' choice- (which opens APEX admin console).  Found I could connect to DB locally (without the @dbname) but not over sqlnet (with @XE). TNS ping found service fine. Issue was windows firewall- turned it off for the local network, and now can connect with sqlplus user/pwd@xe AND the 'Get Started' link to APEX works.